# How to handle error in antlr

Tags: error-handling, antlr

I am new to antlr but I already wrote my first grammar. I have both lexer and parser rules. I have been testing my grammar and it looks that it works. But now I want to handle some errors (for example when it expects int but receives char) and print some error messages as well. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive documentation page available that handles various techniques for error handling in ANTLR on the ANTLR wiki: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery